# enable Dojo support for Forms just on demand in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, dojo

How to have Dojo support disabled by default and just enable it if you want to use it ?

I have the problem that dojo support is automaticly loaded when using any form.
Even without any dojo elements.

I have following configuration:

Bootstrap file

```
    if($this->dojo()->isEnabled()){
```

$this->dojo()->setLocalPath($this->baseUrl().'/js/dojo/dojo/dojo.js')
  ->addStyleSheetModule('dijit.themes.tundra')
                ->setDjConfigOption('usePlainJson',true);
  echo $this->dojo();}

I thought to enable dojo I had to use explicit use something like this in my template/view file:

```
 $this->dojo()->enable();
```

How the tell Zend Framework not to use Dojo by default for Forms ?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
  if ($this->dojo()->isEnabled())
  {
   $this->dojo()
                    ...
   echo $this->dojo();
  }
 ?>
```

Prints the the javascript required to enable dojo if it is enabled. I tend to put this in my layout script,.

I add the dojo as a view helper in the bootstrap inside _initViewHelpers()

```
$view->addHelperPath('Zend/Dojo/View/Helper/', 'Zend_Dojo_View_Helper');
```

Then enable as required in the controller

```
 $this->view->dojo()->enable();
```

If you use a standard Zend_Form with no Dojo elements Dojo shouldn't be loaded.